# Use part of pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I have created a pattern and added it to the swatches. I am designing clothes and I want to use a part of the pattern as a print. How can I extract/isolate a part of the original pattern in Illustrator?

Let us say that the pattern are different faces. I want let say 10 of those faces in a rectangle, and the selection snaps to the content. So I don't need to crop to get the exact part I want.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps look at using a clipping mask? https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html

Comment: I would like the rectangle (the blue one) to snap to the content of the pattern. If you understand? So that it isn't padded.

Comment: Wouldn't  "part of a pattern" actually *be* the pattern? isn't that the definition of "pattern"?

Comment: Yes, but the edges are "ugly". I want to use the part that looks good from all sides.

Comment: That would seem to be more an issue with the construction of the pattern itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clip out just the center square of the pattern, have all elements unlocked and on the same layer. Select the blue and red rectangle, right click and select "Create clipping mask."

To undo, select the mask, right click and select "release clipping mask." Because you are using the clip to make a repeating pattern you will need to clip a very specific area.